# Is there a simpler way to get a character value in java converted to int?

Tags: java

If input is a string "783" and I keep getting chars out of the string via input.charAt(i), is the only way to get the equivalent integer `Character.digit(input.charAt(i),10)` ??

Is there a simpler expression ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the safest way to do it, but you can also simply subtract 48 from the character value, because 0-9 are 48-57 in unicode decimal values.

```
int c = input.charAt(i) - 48;
```

This will of course return unrealistic results if the character is something other than a digit however (for example `'A' - 48` is `17`).

Comment: note that it's probably more readable to do `int c = input.charAt(i) - '0';`

Comment: @JoeK Good note.  I personally prefer 48 over '0' because I often automatically misread `- '0'` as minus zero, so I share it the way I believe clearest.